# how can I manually install a module in qpython?

Tags: pip, qpython

I am using qpython as a non-root user and I have googled it up but all recommendations don't work both manually and using pip...I keep on getting errors...

I get erors when I use both:
    `pip install requests` from pip console
and:
    `import pip
    pip.main(['install','requests'])` on python console

The error is something like:
    `cannot fetch base url https://pypi.python.org/simple/
    could not find any downloads that satisfy the condition requests
    ...`

if there is a workaround or a fix I would be happy to accept...

Comment: Seems like you're sitting behind a proxy since `pip` can't access the PyPI repository. If you request the website via `curl`, like `$ curl -IL https://pypi.python.org/`, do you receive a HTTP 200 back?

Comment: I'm on android so that doesn't work...curl not found

Comment: Ok, then try `ping https://pypi.python.org/`. Although an android developer should definitely have `busybox` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! This fixed my problem once I used the beta v2.1 from

https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython/releases

Google play did not give me the latest version (I had 1.xx)

I was able to use QPYPY to install requests and it automatically installed the required library urllib3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the newest version(>=2.0.7) Installing requests from QPYPI works well in the newest version.  https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython/releases